# SQL float columns: select "where x = 2.0" works, but "where x = 2.1" does not

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, floating-point

I have a Ruby on Rails app with a model `Project`, which has an attribute `wcag_version` of type float.

[image: Screenshot]

I have a record with `wcag_version = 2` and one with `wcag_version = 2.1`:

[image: Screenshot]

What I noticed is that Rails finds the record with `wcag_version = 2` using `Project.where(wcag_version: 2.0)`:

```rb
[4] pry(#<WcagElementsController>)> Project.where(wcag_version: 2.0)
=> [
    [0] #<Project:0x007f9fa900c6e8> { :id => 1 ... }
```

But it doesn't find the record with `wcag_version = 2.1` using `Project.where(wcag_version: 2.1)`:

```rb
[5] pry(#<WcagElementsController>)> Project.where(wcag_version: 2.1)
=> []
```

It seems to be an SQL issue, not a Rails issue though. The generated SQL is:

```rb
[6] pry(#<WcagElementsController>)> Project.where(wcag_version: 2.1).to_sql
=> "SELECT `projects`.* FROM `projects` WHERE `projects`.`wcag_version` = 2.1 ORDER BY `projects`.`name` ASC"
```

Which doesn't return anything either if I execute it manually directly on the database:

[image: Screenshot]

What's going on here? I'm using MySQL by the way.

Comment: Switch to a decimal/numeric data type instead. (If supported.) The float value 2.1 is saved as 2.0999999E+00 something.

Comment: Floats suck.  For a version, I'd save it as varchar.  What if you end up with version `2.1.1` or such?

Comment: Don't use numbers for versions. Use a `VARCHAR`. How would you store the version `3.12.0.7-beta2.1-SNAPSHOT` in a number? Trying to use a number is fighting a battle you cannot win.

Comment: Good point. But how can I compare those VARCHARs?

Comment: Knowing nothing about rails, I'd start with **`wcag_version` = '2.1'**. Single quotes (tick marks) for character data.

Comment: If you're going with varchar, use a pre-defined fixed format. Like `0012.0001.0010.A`, to be able to ORDER BY properly etc.

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with Rails, it seems that I can work around the problem like this:

```rb
Project.all.each do |project|
  if project.wcag_version >= reference_criterion.wcag_version
    # Do stuff
  end
end
```

While this is less performant, it saves me a lot of headache.

For sake of completeness, here's the original code:

```rb
Project.where("wcag_version >= #{reference_criterion.wcag_version}").each do |project|
  # Do stuff
end
```